# how to maintain the relation between tabs opened in a WPF Application

Tags: wpf, prism, tabcontainer

we have a wpf application..in the Home page we have Work,Help,Approve
Search tabs..
When user clicks on the Approve tab and selects a student..if student is 
not qualified then ApproveStudent option is enabled,when clicks StudentApprove 
screen opens in a newtab and there the user can approve the student.

In the StudentApprove screen there Approve and Disqualify buttons, so when they
click the approve the student is approved once he is approved the StudentApprove 
screen should close and take back to the screen from which he come i.e ApproveStudent screen

This is like Ribbonbar

```
  Work,Approve,Search, Help
```

under these ..when they select any option..under these new tab opens, let say search has 3 options..

when selects Approve ..students list is displayed....when clicked on any student another screen is opened...when they click Approve button ..this tab should be closed and take back to Approve screen

Comment: Would you mind including some code to help paint the picture for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ItemsList` and specify

```
[ViewSortHint("01")]
```

when you export your views.

Why do you need `TabContainer` if order is important?